# pure ring homomorphism and Ext functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $f:R\to T$ be pure ring homomorphism of Noetherian commutative ring i.e.;(for every R-module $M$ we have $f\otimes id_M:R\otimes M\to T\otimes M$ injective) and $a$ is proper ideal of $R$, and $aT$ is extension ideal of $a$ in $R$.
I want to find an injective homomorphism between
$$
\phi_i:Ext^i_R(R/a,M)\to Ext_T^i(T/aT,M\otimes T)$$

my approach to proof this is find to injective homomorphism between

$$
\gamma_i:Ext^i_R(R/a,M\otimes T)\to Ext_T^i(T/aT,M\otimes T)$$.

thankfull of anybody to help me to find this homeomorphism